# Git in Terminal is using my real name for commits, how do I make it use my username instead?

Tags: git, github, terminal

When I commit a file from git in terminal to a branch, it shows the commit as being done by my real name. Where is it getting my name from, and how do I change it to show my username? In my Github settings I don't have a Name set, and `git config --get user.name` returns my github username.

Comment: what does `git config --list` tell you? Can you locate your full name there?

Comment: you can also look in ~/.gitconfig (global config) and .git/config (repository config)

Comment: Looked at .gitconfig and `git config --list`, neither have my real name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I commit a file from git in terminal to a branch, it shows the commit as being done by my real name

This is set from the config user.name and user.email

In your repo, make sure to make:

```
git config user.name <yourGitHubAccountName>
git config user.email <yourGitHubAccountEmail>
```

Then make new commits, and see with git log if their author/email is the correct one.

---

Note: as I mentioned in "[How do I make git block commits if user email isn't set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309)", I prefer setting:

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

That will avoid having git trying to guess your username when a local `user.name` is not set.