# Is it possible to have different .gitconfig files for different folders

Tags: git, git-config

Is it possible to have different `.gitconfig` files at the root level of multiple folders? I use a different email address for work repositories and personal repositories, and it's difficult to always remember to set my email on each repository individually.

What I would like is something like the following:

```
git/
├── work/
│   ├── .gitconfig (with user.email set to my work email)
│   ├── app1/
│   ├── app2/
└── home/
    ├── .gitconfig (with user.email set to my home email)
    ├── app3/
    └── app4/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig

Answer (score 4):

In addition of answers mentioned in "[Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4220416/6309)", I prefer an alternative approach:

- don't set any user configuration globally (no `git config --global user.xxx`)
- force Git to ask me who I am at the first commit.
  [This is possible with git 2.8+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309):

  ```
  git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
  ```
- use an alias to set the right user setting.
  On Windows, I use:

  ```
  doskey gcu=git config user.name "My Name" ^&^& git config user.email my-email-for@work.com
  doskey gcuvc=git config user.name "VonC" ^&^& git config user.email my-email-for@opensource.org
  ```

When Git ask me who I am, I type either `gcu` or `gcuvc` depending on the nature of the Git remote repo (work or opensource)

Comment: I marked this answer as useful since it will work as a solution, but it seems to me like it's a pretty common thing for a person to want to use a different email for work and OSS. Is there really no build in mechanism to handle this? I feel like a simple solution to the problem is the one I detailed in my question. I have seen other software such as [NuGet](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied) use the approach and it works very well.

Comment: I agree. I prefer this approach as I want to be sure I didn't mixed up those settings. I confirm them on a per-repo basis.

Comment: This seems like the most straightforward solution at this time, until git supports reading the directory tree up. It isn't that much of a burden.