# How can I reset user information on Magit?

Tags: github, magit

I pushed a project from Spacemacs through Magit. It asked about username, email, password. But I must have typed incorrectly.
It shows that a person with the same username pushed together. But I couldn't find a way to change user information on Magit.

[image]

Comment: This was because git setting was missed. Solved by setting up user information on a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This was because git setting was missed.

You can avoid that with ([for Git 2.8 and more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309))

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

That way, if you try and commit while your `user.name`/`user.email` are *not defined, you would get an error message (instead of default metadata that won't show up properly once pushed)

```
no name was given and auto-detection is disabled
no email was given and auto-detection is disabled
```

Comment: That's what I really needed. thanks! But I don't think that would be safer than just set up user info. Is there any possibility that the setting could be missing again? `git config --global user.name` Maybe I'm just lack of experience.

Comment: @Pete Yes, the goal is not to be "safer": just to force the user to set those settings in case they are missing. `git config --global user.name` is indeed the preferred way.

Comment: I see, I can feel that is useful for when I become to be working with multiple account. Thanks!