# Use current repo's user.email for commits in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I use Git with two different emails / profiles, resulting in:

```
git config user.email >> myRepoEmail@address.com
git config --global user.email >> myGenericEmail@address.com
```

If I use VS Code and open a terminal, my commits use the repo email address; this makes sense because I am effectively using Git (not VSCode). However, if I use the Source Control Git sidebar and type a commit message, `Ctrl+Enter` to commit, etc., then it commits using the global email (`myGenericEmail@address.com`), even though I am working in a repo which has a different setup.

Is there a way to tell VS Code to use the repo's settings for commits, rather than invoking `--global` for commits?

[**EDIT in info from comments**]
I suppose I should mention I have in my gitconfig the command

```
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Users/myname/privateRepoFolder"] 
    path = ~/gitconfig-private
```

and in that alternate gitconfig-private, I have

```
[user] 
    email = myRepoEmail@address.com
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. What is the output of `git config --local --get user.email` ?

Comment: `--global` command outputs `myGenericEmail@address.com`. Omitting it outputs `myRepoEmail@address.com`. But using `--local` outputs nothing. I suppose I should mention I have in my `gitconfig` the command `[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Users/myname/privateRepoFolder"] path = ~/gitconfig-private`, and in that alternate `gitconfig-private`, I have `[user] email = myRepoEmail@address.com`.

Comment: ^That is respected by Git, and is the reason why my repo has `user.email` set to `myRepoEmail` even though I never explicitly set it (using `git config user.email myRepoEmail@address.com`). However, it doesn't seem that VS Code is reading it the same way as Git does.

Comment: On my env, `--local` outputs the repo's email address, which is respected by VS Code when I commit using the Source Control panel. When I remove the `--local` `user.email`, then VS Code reverts to the `--global` `user.email`.

Comment: Right, so I guess the issue is that VS Code doesn't follow the `conditionalIf` that Terminal Git otherwise respects? Seems like a bug to me. Also, do you manually set the `--local` email address on each repo, or is there a way to do this by default? Seems tedious to do it every time. (But it sounds like you *do* do this on your repos.)

Comment: Most of the time, I just use my global settings, and only for special projects/repos do I need set special `--local` `user.*` settings. I would add that I'm on Ubuntu/MacOS, haven't checked your issue yet on Windows, which you seem to be on.

Comment: Have you checked this? [Git integration does not correctly support `includeIf` directive, again](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62921)

Comment: @Gino That worked. Feel free to add as an answer and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally had a chance to check on Windows.

From your comments:

> I suppose I should mention I have in my gitconfig the command
>   `[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Users/myname/privateRepoFolder"]` `path =`
>   `~/gitconfig-private`, and in that alternate gitconfig-private, I have
>   `[user] email = myRepoEmail@address.com`.

On Windows, the `includeIf` [conditional include](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) is a little particular about the path.

**First**, make sure to end the path with a `/` to specify a directory, like in their example:

```
; include for all repositories inside /path/to/group
[includeIf "gitdir:/path/to/group/"]
    path = /path/to/foo.inc
```

So you should use:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Users/myname/privateRepoFolder/"] 
    path = ~/gitconfig-private
```

I found that it also works by ending the path with the *.git* file (to be more explicit).

```
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Users/myname/privateRepoFolder/.git"] 
    path = ~/gitconfig-private
```

**Second**, for VSCode, it only works if you use case-insensitive path matching ([`gitdir/i`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codegitdiricode)):

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:C:/Users/myname/privateRepoFolder/"] 
    path = ~/gitconfig-private
```

This case-insensitive behavior is a known behavior of VSCode.
See the reported issue [Git integration does not correctly support `includeIf` directive](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40354):

> I tried to commit from VSCode, which failed to pick up the includeIf
>   config. Then I ran the wrapper from the command line, and it did pick
>   up the includeIf. I then checked the log:
>
> In VSCode:
>
> `config --get-all user.name in c:\Users\zhuowei\Documents\repos\includeIf`
>
> Outside:
>
> `config --get-all user.name in C:\Users\zhuowei\Documents\repos\includeIf`
>
> Note the difference in the case letter.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I feel like the "known behavior" is a bug but people seem content with forcing case-insensitivity. Maybe off-topic, but isn't something like this a quick fix? At any rate it would prevent people like me from asking this question on SO.

Comment: From the discussion on the issues page, someone did submit a PR for VS Code ([git: fix includeIf on Windows by uppercasing drive letter](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/50376)) and it seemed to only require a few lines, but sadly it was [not merged](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/50376#issuecomment-421297324).

Answer (score 2):

[With Git 2.8 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309), I would actually recommend:

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

And then launch VSCode.
That way, VSCode could not default to a generic email if, for any reason, it does not find your `user.name`/`user.email` configured in any local repo: it would *have* to ask you who you are in that repo.

Comment: It still doesn't fix the issue. When I do this, VS Code is happy to commit. Oddly enough, if I delete the line containing my email from the `--global` config, then VS Code complains that no email is set, although I can still commit from the terminal because it detects my `privateRepo` email address. Note that I don't have `git config user.email myPrivateEmail@a.com` set, but instead I am using a `conditionalIf "gitdir:C:/Users/myPrivateRepos" --> path = ~/.gitconfig-private` which overrides the global email with a new one if the directory is in that folder.

Comment: Somehow it seems that VS Code and Git (from terminal) are using two slightly different invocations of Git. I think it's the same program running, so it's probably just that the calls that VS Code uses are different slightly, though I don't know how.

Comment: @AlexG the idea is to not have any email set in `git config -l --show-origin` => Then this config will force you to set the right email in the right repo.

Comment: Oh.... Yeah, but I was trying to avoid that. I really like the Git conditionalIf method, and seeing as it works on the command line Git, I expected there should be a reason it wouldn't work in VS Code.

Comment: @AlexG Do you mean includeIf? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621480/6309) It should work, with Git 2.13 or more.