# Disable Git Global Username and Email

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

I want to disable the option for my git users that they can set a global username and email. I want it to be **empty** at all.

Now I have the problem, that when some of them set the `global user.name` and `global user.email`, all the commited codes goes by the same name in every project.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you describe how users create their commit ? For example : is it from their own machine ? or do they connect to a shared server and commit from there ?

Comment: @LeGEC they commit from their own machine

Answer (score 9):

Global options are for each user to set (or not)

You would need for them to use, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309):

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

Any new repo will look for `user.email` only in their local `.git/config` file.
And the commit will not proceed if no `user.email` is found in the local git config.

That helps force the user define their identity in each of their repositories.

Comment: i now managed it with ssh connection, this problem occurs when they use the http.

Comment: can they still set or unset the global config settings, specially the global user.name and user.email ?

Comment: @arashyousefi user.name/email config have nothing to do wth authentication though.

Comment: i know it but the global user.name will be set for all committed codes. no matter what the authentication info is.

Comment: @arashyousefi I agree. But that will happen whether they use SSH or HTTPS. With the setting I propose, they will have to set explicitly their `user.name`/`email` per repository, not globally.