# git config username and email set to blank automatically

Tags: git, git-config

I'm having some problems with my global git config. Both username and email is set to blank automatically. I can't figure out if there is a pattern to this behaviour, but more often than not git tells me to set username and email when I'm trying to make a commit.
Updating using `git config --global` or directly editing my `.gitconfig` file both works, but after some time they disappear again.

File content before reset:

```
[user]
    name = <name>
    email = <email>
[core]
    editor = atom --wait
    excludesfile = /Users/christian/.gitignore_global
[pull]
    rebase = false
```

File content after reset:

```
[user]
    name = 
    email = 
[core]
    editor = atom --wait
    excludesfile = /Users/christian/.gitignore_global
[pull]
    rebase = false
```

Comment: Since `git config --global` works by writing to your global `.gitconfig` file, anything else that *destroys* that file (or sets it back to some old contents) would undo the setting. Look for things that change files. Having your home directory on some sort of file-sharing / web-synchronizing service would do it, for instance, as would login startup commands that erase and reset all configuration.

Comment: You are not losing your mind, I've got exactly the same problem on my Mac (11.0.1) where the `name =` and `email =` values are vanishing from the `[user]` section of my `.gitconfig`. Curiously the `signingkey = xxxxx` is untouched, as is the rest of the file.

Comment: Are you using Atom?  I'm having the same problem and I'm suspicious that Atom might be to blame but I'm still investigating

Comment: @IsaacBetesh I am indeed using atom, but not for any interactions with git. I do all that in Terminal.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh I am also using Atom and experienced this issue today for the first time. Any ideas? What made you suspicious about Atom?

Comment: My suspicions were correct.  This is caused by toggling between 2 tabs in Atom, if they contain files from different repos.  Closing a tab, if it results in a tab from another repo becoming active, would also cause this.  This has already been reported to atom: https://github.com/atom/github/issues/2558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed by [Isaac Betesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633753/isaac-betesh) this is an Atom problem, where some interactions with tabs from different repositories wipe out the global user/email config. The issue is at: https://github.com/atom/github/issues/2558

I've temporarily worked around the problem by removing the write permission from `~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 0):

In addition of checking what could delete your `~/.gitconfig` global Git configuration, check also if `git config user.useConfigOnly` is set to true.

[Since Git 2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309), that would also force you to set your user.name/email for each repository.

You would also see the effect of that configuration in the error message:

```
no name was given and auto-detection is disabled
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If not, then it is back to check if, when you have the issue, your global `.gitconfig` is deleted or somehow changed/reset.

Comment: user.useConfigOnly is **not** set in my config. It's also only the `[user]` part of my `~/.gitconfig` that is reset. Have a `[core]` section, which is always untouched.

Comment: @ChristianOlsen Is that ~/.gitconfig deleted when you have to update your user.name/email?

Comment: @ChristianOlsen Was the file modified then, when your user.name/email went missing?

Comment: Yes! It just happened again. Checking `ls -lc ~/.gitconfig`, I can see it was changed. Any tips on how I can track down the process responsible?

Comment: @ChristianOlsen What is its content when it is changed?

Comment: updated my original post with file content.

Comment: @ChristianOlsen sothe values are reset to <empty>. Is there any `GIT_xxx` user variable set or unset at any point (as in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing)

Comment: I'm not setting any of those variables at any point. Generally I'm just using standard git commands, e.g. `git status`, `git add`, `git commit`, `git restore` etc.