# git config for specific local repository did not work

Tags: git, github

My development environment:

```
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets> git --version
git version 2.30.0.windows.1
```

Windows 10 x64 version 2004. My repository https://github.com/donhuvy/jqxwidgets (just for learning a jQuery plug-in framework). In my PC has Github Desktop for Windows, but I use it for other project.

(1) I tried config for local git repository

```
git config user.name "Do Nhu Vy"
git config user.email "donhuvy@outlook.com"
```

it did not work.

(2) I tried config for local git repository

```
git config user.name "Do Nhu Vy"
git config user.email donhuvy@outlook.com
```

it did not work.

(3) I tried use Windows PowerShell (Administrator)

```
git config user.name "Do Nhu Vy"
git config user.email "donhuvy@outlook.com"
```

it did not work.

[image]

I don't want use `git config --global ...` because on my PC has many projects has different remote server and different users.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd d:
PS D:\> cd .\github\
PS D:\github> cd .\jqxwidgets\
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets> ls


    Directory: D:\github\jqxwidgets


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         1/19/2021   2:48 PM                .idea
d-----         1/19/2021   2:41 PM                jqxGrid
-a----         1/19/2021   2:39 PM           1714 .gitignore
-a----         1/19/2021   2:39 PM           1544 LICENSE
-a----         1/19/2021   2:39 PM             12 README.md


PS D:\github\jqxwidgets> git config user.name "Do Nhu Vy"
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets> git config --list
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=schannel
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=true
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager-core
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=main
user.name=vyolbius
user.email=74403808+vyolbius@users.noreply.github.com
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/donhuvy/jqxwidgets.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
user.email=donhuvy@hotmail.com
user.name=Do Nhu Vy
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets>
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets>
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets> git --version
git version 2.30.0.windows.1
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets>
PS D:\github\jqxwidgets>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local config will overwrite any global configuration.
Check yours with:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config --show-origin --show-scope -l
```

Try and make a new commit: it should be authored with the right user name/email.

I always use (as [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309)):

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

That way, I am forced to set the right user.name/email on each new local Git repository.

Comment: This is my power shell log https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/ebd637cd4b02ae5130533a431bf02d64 and commit https://github.com/donhuvy/jqxwidgets but I still see `user.name=vyolbius` I tend/want/imagine it is `user.name=donhuvy` .

Comment: @DoNhuVy Yes, you see it in the global config: it is overridden by the local config, so it is all good.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `git config --local`? Also the global setting doesn't overwrite all other projects, rather it creates a default configuration that is used unless local settings are different.

So if you set your global email

```sh
git config --global user.email "donhuvy@outlook.com"
```

That will only affect repositories where the email isn't set locally. To set an email locally do

```sh
git config --local user.email "donhuvy@outlook.com"
```

The global and local flags work for all and are necessary for all settings.

Comment: It did not work as you and me expected https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/a55b0d07036788a42e5f9bf983e7fae7#file-git_local-log-L203-L204

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/105006606-78390200-5a69-11eb-968b-dea9c63b1b8b.png

Comment: is that folder a git repo? Does it have a hidden `.git` folder? Also try to list it with `git config --list --local`

Comment: I see screenshot again, it is exactly local git repository in my PC. Oh, it work now https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/105015061-b9ceaa80-5a73-11eb-959f-a4971bd3f7fa.png

Answer (score 1):

It's not broken.

> ```
> PS D:\github\jqxwidgets> git config --list
> [snippage]
> user.name=vyolbius
> [snippage]
> user.name=Do Nhu Vy
> ```

The first value comes from a "higher" or "more global level" / less-applicable setting, and the second value comes from the "more local level" / more-applicable setting.  The second value *overrides* the first value.

(There are some Git settings that are cumulative.  For these, you must inspect all the values listed by `git config --list` or `git config --get-all`.  But `user.name` and `user.email` are not cumulative; they are last-one-listed-wins.)